# How do I display the contents of a row in vector of vector from reverse in C++?

Tags: c++

To display the contents of a vector of vector in C++, we  use nested for loops. Something like this:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < x[i].size(); j++) 
            std :: cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        std :: cout << std :: endl;
    }
```

(Here x is a vector of vector.)

But say I want to display the contents of a row in a reverse manner and all the other rows in regular fashion. How would I do it? Should I reverse the row separately and print the vector? Or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Which row is "a row" and which rows are "other rows"? Could you show the example of the contents of `x` and the expected output?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Suppose I've a 2D vector of size 2. I've in row one some numbers say: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and in row two I've: (21, 22, 23, 24, 25). I want to display the contents of row one in reverse manner (something like: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) and the contents of row two in regular manner (21, 22, 23, 24, 25). What I did was I reversed row one separately and printed the contents of the vector. All I wanted to know is if there's another way of doing this?

Comment: How do you decide which rows to show in the original order, and which in reverse?

Comment: Please add that information with the example to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but.

Either of this 2

this will reverse the order of `i`

```cpp
for (int i = x.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].size(); j++){
            std :: cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl'
}
```

basically, what happen here is that, I started the `i` at the last index of the vector, to reverse the order

or

this will reverse the order of `j`

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = x[1].size() - 1; j >= 0; --j){
            std::cout << x[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

in here, i started the `j` at the last vector index of the vector.

Take note, that don't use auto for the initialization part of the `for` loop (in this case), because if you do `auto i = x.size() - 1` you will get an unsigned long, and cause some trouble since this loop will stop only if the value is <= -1.

> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and in row two I've: (21, 22, 23, 24, 25). I want to display the contents of row one in reverse manner (something like: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) and the contents of row two in regular manner (21, 22, 23, 24, 25)

If this is what you want, then

```cpp
bool notReverse = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
        int sIndex = notReverse ? 0 : x[0].size() - 1,   // starting index
            eIndex = notReverse ? x[0].size() : -1,      // last index
            mod_j  = notReverse ? 1 : -1;                // modifier
            
        for(int j = sIndex; j != eIndex; j+=mod_j){
            std::cout << x[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
        notReverse = true;
}
```

I've created some variables that will decide whether the value is gonna be reverse or not.

Answer (score -1):

Although you can change the direction of the loop, if more instructions are working in the original direction (i++), you should rather just change the index:

```
auto y=x;
for (auto i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < x[i].size(); j++){
        std :: cout << x[i][j] << " ";//comment 1            
        std :: cout << y[(x.size()-1)-i][j] << " ";//comment 2
    }
    std :: cout << std :: endl;
}
```

comment 1: commands that are using the original indexing direction (0,1,2...)

comment 2: reverse indexing with the "i" iterator, starting in the last position (x.size()-1) ("-1" because the index of the fist element is zero). Please, take a look of this:

```
normal indexing (i++):
0,1,2,3,4,5
reverse indexing:
5,4,3,2,1,0
size:5 elements
size - (each index in normal indexing):
5-0,5-1,5-2,5-3,5-4,5-5
  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0    -> reverse indexing
```

it's important to handle the indexing in both forms (changing the order while indexing and changing the order while looping through the elements), and I suggest you see also @Renz Aguirre's answer.